# How to combine two columns in web sql

Tags: sql, web-sql

I am working with web sql. I have built many tables and trying to get data from the database. Problem is that when is try to combine two columns it returns 0 in that column.

```
(t1.team_name+' '+t2.team_name) AS "Teams"
```

or

```
 CONCAT(t1.team_name,' ',t2.team_name) AS "Teams"
```

These do not work. Am i doing something wrong because separately they return the text.

Comment: What do you mean "do not work"?  How does it not work?  Do you get an error message?  What is the error message?  Do you get incorrect results?  What are the incorrect results that you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite (which I belive Web SQL is based on) you can concatenate strings with `||`so try this:

```
t1.team_name || ' ' || t2.team_name AS "Teams"
```